# Automatic page redirect with jquery after css animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, redirect

Please check out the following link for reference:

http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/CSS3TimedNotifications/

Now, after the completion of the css animation, how do I automatically redirect to another page?

The event sequence should like this -

1. I click on  the button
2. The notifications appear and disappear
3. I'm automatically redirected to another page.

Comment: It's easy: use callback.

Comment: Have a look at this **[Using jQuery to Detect When CSS3 Animations and Transitions End](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your HTML and CSS, you need to add this:

```
$("input.fire-check").bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e){
    window.location.href = "http://google.com/";
});
```

**EDIT 1**

I just realized you are not using jQuery. Here is what you need to add(and remove what you added before):

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){//detects css transition end on all browsers
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

var transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
var input = document.querySelector(".fire-check");//get first element with class fire-check
input.addEventListener(transitionEnd, redirect, false);//event listener redirects when transitions end
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "http://google.com/";
}
```

**EDIT 3** 
Oops my bad I have slightly changed the above code. Let me know if it works.

You dont need to add jQuery but if you want to here is what you have to add in between your `<head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added what you suggested, still it isn't working! I've no clue where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Aah..still no luck.. but thanks for your effort..can you tell me how to do it using jquery?

Comment: I've tried both.. didn't work.. neither the js nor the jquery.. and I have no clue why...anyway I'm done with that experiment. Thanks for your immense help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ID").bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e){
    window.location.href = "someurl";
});
```

Comment: Could you take some time out to check this [link](constantcontrast.com/animedemo) and let me know what's needed to be done?

Comment: @SamDG add this JS to your HTML file. What it does is wait for the CSS animation to finish and then redirects to "someurl".

Comment: @stackErr It doesn't seem to work as I'm having trouble finding out the right #ID. Could you check the link and let me know which one should it be.